# jQuery Validate ignoring rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This problem is holding me now for a while. It's probable an easy thing but at this hour I'm not seeing it. HTML & JavaScript is included below. jQuery 1.8.3 is loaded before jQuery validate and no JS errors are in there.

The problem is actually that even when submitting an empty value, the validator just accepts it as an accepted entry and submits the form (no errors in console).

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="reactieform">
<input type="hidden" name="reactie" value="1" />

<table style="float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td width="250">Voornaam</td>
        <td width="650"><input maxlength="150" type="text" name="voornaam" /></td>
        <td width="100"></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Reactie opslaan" /></td>
    </tr>                   
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#reactieform').validate({            
        voornaam: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 rules:{
         voornaam: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
         }
       }
```

Comment: Damn! You got it. Me is terribly blind at this hour it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Your title was the answer _jQuery Validate ignoring *RULES*_

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing the `rules` option entirely.   Your rules declaration must be placed *inside* the `rules` option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#reactieform').validate({    
        rules: {
            voornaam: {
                 required: true,
                 minlength: 10
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4kXuF/**